# Restart css3 keyframes animation of a div

Tags: javascript, css, animation, slider, restart

I am a beginner in css3 keyfarames animation. Now am making a animated banner for a site, 
http://opustestsite.com/SYNRAD/

I have to restart all the animations of the slider div.
1. when clicking on previous and next buttons.
2. When another banner div comes automatically.

Please help me

Comment: how about adding the animation in a css class and applying it to the div on click..?

Comment: Not real sure what your problem is...

Comment: in the above above link i have only created one banner animation div and I am about to create four more banner slides. But I want to to display the animation from the beginning when each slider div comes. And there is two chances , those are.. 1) Automatically after 30 seconds, 2) When user clicks next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use add and remove classes with animation reserve.
Check this stack anwser:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049271/931067